# Calendar Not Appearing Where It's Supposed To! Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, calendar

I'm pretty new to jQuery. I have a form with some datepicker calendars, but when the calendar fields are clicked on, the actual calendar doesn't display next to the field. Instead, it appears right at the top of my page. Can anyone spot why this is happening? Thanks.

```js
$("#datepicker6").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

$("#datepicker7").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});
```

```css
 .ui-datepicker {
   border-radius: 1px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 #datepicker-inline {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 1% auto;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-header {
   border-radius: 1px;
   background: #ffffff;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-prev,
 .ui-datepicker-next {
   border-radius: 1px;
 }

 .ui-datepicker thead {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 1px;
 }
 .ui-datepicker th {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 8pt;
 }
 .ui-datepicker td span,
 .ui-datepicker td a {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   width: 32px;
   height: 32px;
   line-height: 32px;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
   background: #ededed;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
   background: #f4f4f4;
   color: #b4b3b3;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
   background: #f7f7f7;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
   background: #6eafbf;
   color: #e0e0e0;
   border: 1px solid #55838f;
   position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id='UIItem20' style="display: inline-block">
  What is the estimated deployment start date?
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker6">
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<div id='UIItem21' style="display: inline-block">
  What is the estimated deployment completion date?
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker7">
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited the question and added your code to the snippet.

**Even in the snippet** it seems to be **working fine** (calendar just below input field). There may be **some other style in your page** that is making the datepicker it behave like you told.

Tip: use your browser's developer tool (F12) over the datepicker element to see where the styles applied came from.

Look at the code with some improvements.

```js
$("#datepicker6").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

$("#datepicker7").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
   border-radius: 1px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 #datepicker-inline {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 1% auto;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-header {
   border-radius: 1px;
   background: #ffffff;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-prev,
 .ui-datepicker-next {
   border-radius: 1px;
 }

 .ui-datepicker thead {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 1px;
 }
 .ui-datepicker th {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 8pt;
 }
 .ui-datepicker td span,
 .ui-datepicker td a {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   width: 32px;
   height: 32px;
   line-height: 32px;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
   background: #ededed;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
   background: #f4f4f4;
   color: #b4b3b3;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
   background: #f7f7f7;
 }

 .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
   background: #6eafbf;
   color: #e0e0e0;
   border: 1px solid #55838f;
   position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></style>


<div id='UIItem20' style="display: inline-block">
  <p>What is the estimated deployment start date?</p>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker6" />
</div>

<div id='UIItem21' style="display: inline-block">
  <p>What is the estimated deployment completion date?</p>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker7" />
</div>
```

Tip2: Avoid using `<br>` tags to space lines you your html. Use classes and css attributes like margin, padding, line-height, etc... (its a better practice)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. So I had a further look into it and it turns out that they display correctly in Firefox but not in IE, (version 8). Is there anything specifically that I need to look at to fix this?

Comment: @ScottCoates Maybe its your Jquery Ui version. Take a look at this: http://jquery.com/browser-support/